# not able to search text by Browser's ctrl+F, using CanvasKit Flutter

Tags: flutter, performance, navigation, flutter-web, canvaskit

trying find workaround for Flutter web!

need Searchable text by Browser's ctrl+F

Preferred - [How to use Skia / CanvasKit in Flutter Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583461/how-to-use-skia-canvaskit-in-flutter-web)

To run with CanvasKit:

```
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
```

shortcut:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```

check code snippet - [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can text in a Flutter web app be made searchable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448168/can-text-in-a-flutter-web-app-be-made-searchable)