# Search and transverse to the specific string within document in flutter application

Tags: html, flutter, view

In my **flutter** application I am fetching HTML data by a network call (API) and show this inside a container as HTML view using package ['flutter_html: ^2.2.1'](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html).
The rendering is ok and it serves my first requirement.

However for an example, when we write any document in MSWord or other editor we can simply search anything using **Ctrl+F** and it shows the result in highlighted text and from the search area we can easily transverse  to the desired search string, no matter whether this text in any line.
Similarly i'm looking for such kinds of solution which allow me to search, highlight text and transverse over the HTML document.

Please guide me how to do this or suggest me any package to achieve this.

Comment: may this help you , https://medium.com/@nogadev/highlight-search-results-in-flutter-66f03974ddec

Comment: @AbolfazlMashhadi this won't help me, the gist is no more in thread